# Importing multiple CSV files in to SQLite - each CSV has 1 matching column

Tags: sql, json, rest, api, sqlite

I have 2 CSV files, each with the following sample data:

File 1:

```
column1,column2,column3
somedata,somemoredata,evenmoredata
```

File2:

```
column1,column4,column5
somedata,differentdata,moredifferentdata
```

column1 is always guaranteed to have the same value while column's 2, 3 and 4 will be different.

I would like to have 1 SQL Table in SQLite with 5 columns (all of type varchar) where the data has been imported from the 2 CSV files.

Not noing much about SQL and even less so about SQLite, is this possible?

*Just some background on where the CSV files come from: I am retreiving JSON data from 2 REST API Endpoints, then using JQ to extract certain JSON arrays in to CSV format. In the above example data, column1 is the same JSON data in both REST Endpoints.*

Comment: I would populate 2 different tables and then identify a key to join them together - we can't provide much advice without knowledge of the data and how you will be using it.

Comment: do some quick reading on relationships, and entities, and keys which will provide dependence and determinence between your associated tables.

Comment: How/where are looking to store the values into the SQLite database? Is this from the same code that retrieves your JSON? Or are you looking to build a tool to read the CSV files and store them off? Bit unclear how you're looking to achieve this.

Comment: So the data basically comes from the Spotify Web API, one Endpoint returns Songs from a playlist while the other Endpoint returns audio features for a given track. Here is the bash script I am working on, I am planning to the call SQLite from the script but also wanted to save the CSV for later use. So far the script only gets JSON from the first Endpoint, still working on the second. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/64b2b6d12b/spotkey/master/spotkey.sh

Comment: The column1 in this case is known as the Spotify Track URI. Example: "spotify:track:3n3Ppam7vgaVa1iaRUc9Lp"

Comment: I still think that having separate entities for these data-sets is the way forward, that way you can relate the tables to one another.